# How to fix google chrome menu nav bar layout issue with bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This looks just right in firefox, but google changes the layout.  I am not sure what I am missing in using bootstrap 3.

Looks wrong in google chrome:

[image]

This is how it is suppose to look - like it does in firefox with the code below:

[image]

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">Logo</a>
            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="navbar-brand pull-left" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical glyphicon-lg pull-right"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                   <form method="get" action="home.php">
                        <div class="input-group search">
                                <!-- Search Button -->                          
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button  class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                </span>
                                <!-- /End search Button Icon -->
                                <!-- Search Text -->
                                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style= "border: 0;" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for ..." />
                                <!-- End Search text -->
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class='input-group search'>
                        <form action='home.php' method='post' >
                            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-lg' name='Create' id='Create' value='Create' />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Bootstrap

> Place form content within .navbar-form for proper vertical alignment and collapsed behavior in narrow viewports. Use the alignment options to decide where it resides within the navbar content.

So you can add the `navbar-form` class to your `<form>`s to fix the issue reported here.

```
<form class="navbar-form" ... >
```

Codepen to show you that it appears the same in IE, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBmdQq